# querySelector on inner template element

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, css

I'm trying to reach a lightning icon in my component and it is not working. It is wrapped with a `<template if:true={condition}>`

```
<template>
<template if:true={condition0}>
    <div id={uniqueId}>
        <div class="slds-class">
            <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_large">
                <template if:true={condition1}>
                    <span style="font-size:32px;">                                               
                        <i class={icon} lwc:dom="manual"></i>
                    </span>                                                 
                </template>
                <template if:true={condition2}>
                    <lightning-icon class="sf-icon-class" icon-name={icon} size="medium"></lightning-icon>  
                </template>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
</template>
```

I'm able to reach ".slds-avatar" but not ".sf-icon-class"

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? can you show full code from JS also

Comment: Just trying to style the lightning-icon (background color) based on a parameter that is being passed from the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you implemented the code (as you are not showing full related code), but you can try below:

1. Change handlers/connected callback will be invoked before DOM is loaded, so `querySelector`s will give `null`.
2. Use `renderedCallback` to access elements and implement logic. BUT you should be very careful to implement manual `check` whether the intended logic needs to run again when re-rendered.

Below logic implementation will work:

Parent.html:

```
<template>
    <c-child icon="utility:activity"></c-child>
</template>
```

child.html:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={condition0}>
        <div id={uniqueId}>
            <div class="slds-class">
                <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_large">
                    <template if:true={condition1}>
                        <span style="font-size:32px;">
                            <i class={icon} lwc:dom="manual"></i>
                        </span>
                    </template>
                    <template if:true={condition2}>
                        <lightning-icon class="sf-icon-class" icon-name={icon} size="medium">
                        </lightning-icon>
                    </template>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

child.js:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Child extends LightningElement {
    @api icon;
    renderedCallback() {
        if (!this.iconStyleSetDone) {
            if (this.icon === 'utility:activity')
                this.template.querySelector('.sf-icon-class').style.background = 'white';
            else
                this.template.querySelector('.sf-icon-class').style.background = 'grey';
            this.iconStyleSetDone = true;
        }
    }
    get condition0() {
        return true;
    }
    get condition1() {
        return true;
    }
    get condition2() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the level of detail. I had tried both hooks and it seems that I did something wrong when using renderedCallback as I was not being able to select it. I just tested it with your examples notation and no issue. I will implement an initialize value per the documentation to avoid unnecessary calls when rendering.